# Running find('all') or find('first') on identical set of conditions in Cake 2

Tags: cakephp

In a `controller/index` action in my CakePHP2 app, I have

```
$this->Model-find('all',array( ... lots conditions and things... ));
```

Then, in `controller/view` I have:

```
$this->Model-find('first',array( ... lots conditions and things... ));
```

Both of these work really well, but I'm obviously repeating a large chunk of code (namely, the find conditions, field list etc) with the only two differences being that in the first one I'm doing `find('all')` and in the second one I'm doing `find('first')` and providing the id as one of the conditions.

Is there a way that I can move the conditions into the model and then run different types of find on those conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a method in Youur Model:

```
public function getConditions($id = null) {
   return array( ... lots conditions and things... );
}
```

somewhere in this method just test if `(!empty($id))` to return correct result. (You haven't provide the 'conditions and things' so I can't write the exact code here...

and use it in both controler actions:

```
$this->Model->find('first', $this->Model->getConditions()));

$this->Model->find('all', $this->Model->getConditions()));
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can move your query into model class as a function/method. see sample bellow for post model:

```
class Post extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Post';

    public function getAll() {
       return $this->find('all', array('limit' => 20, 'order' => 'Post.created DESC'));
    }
}
```

and call it on your controller by $this->Model->getAll();

```
$this->Post->getAll();
```

You can also add parameter to your function.

Answer (score 0):

Add the conditions as an attribute of your controller

```
class FoosController extends AppController{

    public $conditions = array( ... lots conditions and things... )

    public function index(){
        $this-Foo->find('all', $this->conditions);
    }

    public function view(){
        $this-Foo->find('first', $this->conditions);
    }
}
```